# Switching from LMDE to debian testing + LMDE

Tags: distributions, repository

I currently have LMDE UP8 with cinnamon installed. I want to add debian testing repos for all my packages but I still want to keep LMDE repos for specific packages like cinnamon, firefox, flashplayer, etc.

My `/etc/apt/sources.list` is blank.

`/etc/apt/preferences.d/official-package-repositories.pref`

```
Package: *
Pin: release o=linuxmint
Pin-Priority: 700

Package: *
Pin: origin packages.linuxmint.com
Pin-Priority: 700

Package: *
Pin: release o=Ubuntu
Pin-Priority: 500
```

How can I add debian testing repos?

Comment: I recommend against this unless you really, really, *really* know what you're doing. Mixing distribution flavors is a tricky business to begin with, and Testing is where debian puts stuff when they *think* they've gotten most of the obvious bugs out and are ready to see how to integrate it with the rest of the debian packages. Intercompatibility with other distros is an afterthought at *best*.

Comment: @Shadur LMDE is just snapshots of testing so doesn't that make it testing+cinnamon+nemo+(mint specific tools) ?

Comment: No, from what I can see Mint is a hodgepodge of debian and ubuntu packages slightly reconfigured and crammed together in a way they hope won't break too many things in stuff their target area cares about. I stand by my advice.